Orange marks on ceiling underneath bathroom
Orange marks on ceiling underneath bathroom . Can anyone confirm if it’s a mould or is it a leakage from the bathroom. Suggest the best approach to proceed. Much worries.


These are water stains. How long have they been there? Where are these stains relative to your bathroom fixtures? If you have fixed the issue, apply a stain blocking paint to the affected area(s) and repaint the entire ceiling for uniformity.

It's water stains. A fixture is leaking. In most cases it's the toilet bowl to flange seal.

Don't wait on this.  Worst case could be a a leak in the toilet pipe you could have sewage leaking into the ceiling.

Those are water stains. Something is dripping from upstairs. Check all the caulking and grout lines in the upstairs bath for cracks. Those would be the easiest fixes. The next would be the wax ring for the toilet, not difficult to replace. If these stains have just appeared, a fast find & fix could prevent replacing ceiling drywall. Wiping with some bleach often will remove the stain. If the leaking been going on for awhile, the drywall will probably need replacing so cutting out the section would allow you to more easily find the leak and any mold that could be forming.

There is an outside chance that these are old stains from before a (half) repair. It is not likely that they are simply old stains from a fixed leak, but if you can't find a leak and they aren't changing shape...
